# "In Failover" or "Failed over"

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Failover is defined as:
"A backup operational mode in which the functions of a system component are assumed by secondary system components when the primary component becomes unavailable through either failure or scheduled down time."

So when a system is in this "backup operational mode", is it "In Failover" or is it "Failed over" (and should there be a dash there?)

This will be used in a software user interface showing the state of the system.

Comment: "In failover" is correct. "failed over" is an entirely different discussion.

Comment: If you're describing the second (back-up) system, one sincerely hopes that that system has **not** failed - so "failed over" is clearly inappropriate.  But the **whole** system is in "fail-over mode".

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the system *has failed over* and is thus *in failover*.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fail_over

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/failover

---

... and a side debate about why "failover" is not a verb, and does not conjugate as such:

http://notaverb.com/failover